# Reading a line from a file with Android SDK

Tags: android, file

I've tried for three days now, and I cannot get my program to read from this or any other file. Please help! I've tried creating another project and placing this which didn't work either.

```
    TextView orangeTitle;
    String line;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameplay);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    try {
        cardReader(null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setOrange();
}

public String cardReader(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Documents\\Android Development\\HumorMe\\assets\\orangecards.txt");
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    line = bfr.readLine();
    bfr.close();
    return line;
}

public void setOrange() 
{
    orangeTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    orangeTitle.setText(line);
}
```

Comment: you are reading a file stored in your windows partition. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access your assets via their path on you PC. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getAssets%28%29 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html for how to access asset files. For example:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("orangecards.txt")
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I spent that much time and it was a simple solution. This worked perfect though! Thank you for your help, Neil!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to read a file from your computer, which isn't possible since your code is running on a separate Android device. Try putting a text file on the SD card of the device and running something like:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.txt");
```